# How to obtain fieldnames in Python with SQLite3?

Tags: python, sqlite, odbc, field

In javascript, with ODBC, you can obtain fieldnames:

```
var rs = cn.Execute("SELECT ...
rs.Fields(0).Name = "date"
rs.Fields(1).Name = "qty"
rs.Fields(2).Name = ...
```

I would like to do the same thing in Python with SQLite.
Do you know how to do that?

Regards,

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831371/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-list-of-column-names-in-sqlite ?