# Is There a Way To Select All Columns From The Table And Except One Column

Tags: python

I have been using sqlite3 with python for creating databases. Till Now I have been successful,
But Unfortunately I have No way Out Of This. I have A Table With 63 columns but I Want To Select Only 62 Out Of Them, I am Sure That I can write The Names of The Columns In The Select Statement. But Writing 62 Of Them seems like a non-logical(for a programmer like me) idea for me. I am using Python-sqlite3 databases. Is There A Way Out Of This

I'm Sorry If I am Grammarly Mistaken.

Thanks in **advance**

Answer (score 1):

With Sqlite, you can:

1. [do a `PRAGMA table_info(tablename);` query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7831585/51685) to get a result set that describes that table's columns
2. pluck the column names out of that result set and remove the one you don't want
3. compose a column list for the select statement using e.g. `', '.join(column_names)` (though you might want to consider a higher-level SQL statement builder instead of playing with strings).

## Example

A simple example using a simple table and an in-memory SQLite database:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.executescript("CREATE TABLE kittens (id INTEGER, name TEXT, color TEXT, furriness INTEGER, age INTEGER)")

columns = [row[1] for row in con.execute("PRAGMA table_info(kittens)")]
print(columns)
selected_columns = [column for column in columns if column != 'age']
print(selected_columns)
query = f"SELECT {', '.join(selected_columns)} FROM kittens"
print(query)
```

This prints out

```
['id', 'name', 'color', 'furriness', 'age']
['id', 'name', 'color', 'furriness']
SELECT id, name, color, furriness FROM kittens
```

Comment: But Where Should I use That function... My Code Is as Follows

Comment: def viewData():
    con = sqlite3.connect("student.db");
    cur = con.cursor();
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM StudentDatabaseTable");
    rows = cur.fetchall();
    con.close();
    return rows;#Please exclude The Commas

Comment: Put your code in your question, not in a comment.

Comment: I edited my answer to add a full example.